# Why information about lock appears so late, after 5-6 seconds?

Tags: c#, transactions, odbc, progress-4gl, openedge

I have simple application which have two buttons.
First button create transaction and hold it for 30 seconds before commit it.

Second button execute method where I tried to update the same record.

My point is to get information about locked record but exception is throwed after 5-6 seconds.

In PROGRESS, information about lock appears instantly.

How Can I achieve a similar efficiency in C#?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(  () =>
        {
            using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("DSN=myDSN;UID=root;PWD=qweasd"))
            {
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();
                OdbcTransaction transaction = null;

                command.Connection = con;

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    while (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }

                    transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

                    command.Connection = con;
                    command.Transaction = transaction;

                    command.CommandText = " UPDATE pub.ad_mstr SET ad_line1 = 'button3' where ad_mstr.ad_addr = 'abcdefgh'  ";

                    command.CommandTimeout = 1;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }


                    transaction.Commit();

                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
            //_startedTransaction1 = true;
        }); /* Task.Run ( () => */
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_startedTransaction1)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("DSN=myDSN;UID=root;PWD=qweasd"))
                {
                    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();
                    OdbcTransaction transaction = null;

                    command.Connection = con;

                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        while (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(10);
                        }

                        transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

                        command.Connection = con;
                        command.Transaction = transaction;

                        command.CommandText = " UPDATE pub.ad_mstr SET ad_name = 'button1' where ad_mstr.ad_addr = 'abcdefgh'  ";

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        transaction.Commit();

                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    //_startedTransaction1 = true;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            //_startedTransaction1 = false;
        }

    }
```

I want to add that my 'myDSN' is with COMMITED isolation level.
Exception which appears after 5-6 seconds is :

"System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal pgoe1023.dll ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Failure getting record lock on a record from table PUB.ad_mstr."

Comment: Do you _really_ want queries to abort immediately when there's a lock on a record? If there's a normal update going on, you'd be throwing errors even if the update took a single millisecond if the other thread just checked at that moment and gave up right away. Normally you'd want deadlocks to resolve immediately, but wait for normal slow queries for at least a few seconds before throwing errors.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I just need to know as fast as possible if my query is locked and then possibly perform some actions.

Comment: [Wouldn't seem to be settable to below 5 seconds](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P9177), however I'm no PROGRESS guru by any means so may be missing something.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? Conflicting locks usually indicates a need to change the design.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : I think this parameter is for something else.
In PROGRESS I can get information about locks  
immediately and this parameter means how much time need to wait before surrender.

Like I said information about record locks appears instantly.

Comment: @TimKuehn : Im sorry if I didn't write it clearly.
In my scenario : multiple users probably will want to update the same record in the same time on production database.
I need to allow first one updating record as long as necessary and inform rest of users that the record is locked as fast as possible.
Exactly, as fast as it is in PROGRESS programs.
Probably some users will be virtual machines and locking thousands of records in same time. 
I need information about locks instantly.

Comment: I'd say your design needs to be reviewed and altered - having multiple users trying to update the same thing at the same time is just begging for refactoring.

Comment: @TimKuehn : It's only worst case scenario but it could happen.

So there is no way to get this information ( about locks when they appear ) faster than 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should set the -SQLLockWaitTimeout parameter on your DB server:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/What-is-the-SQLLockWaitTimeout-Parameter

Comment: If 5 seconds is  minimum value of this parameter so I guess I cannot achieve faster response with information about locks.